# IBM Worklight - Custom Authentication

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

When trying to authenticate an adapter using custom authenticator and login module, I am facing the following exception.

```
[ERROR   ] FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project /CustomAuth [project CustomAuth]
Error creating bean with name 'taskManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/D:/worklight_workspace/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService' while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/D:/worklight_workspace/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginConfigurationServiceBean#7cffa209' of type [com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginConfigurationServiceBean] while setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginConfigurationServiceBean#7cffa209' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/D:/worklight_workspace/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Class 'com.mypackage.MyCustomLoginModule' defined in login module 'CustomLoginModule' in the authentication configuration file doesn't exist.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application CustomAuth started in 0.948 seconds.
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An execption occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class &#39;com.mypackage.MyCustomLoginModule&#39; defined in login module &#39;CustomLoginModule&#39; in the authentication configuration file doesn&#39;t exist.
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.verifyServletInitialized(AuthenticationFilter.java:300)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class 'com.mypackage.MyCustomLoginModule' defined in login module 'CustomLoginModule' in the authentication configuration file doesn't exist.
    ... 5 more
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Read the exception, follow the information it provides. Verify your class is properly set up and referenced?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your project war does not contain your java classes for some reason. I am not sure why, need more information on that, but I think that by deleting your bin folder and rebuilding all artifact you will be able to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Look your JDK version between your generated binary app and your Worklight server version. You can check if the binary is generated in Windows or Unix based operative system and redeploy your app taking the server operative system as a base for your binary app.

Answer (score 0):

Need to write their own java class for custom authentication. These java class will act like authenticator and challenger while writing a custom authentication method.

Please find the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_oauth_custom_authentication.html?lang=en) for the HTTP based custom authentication.